# Sharepoint document library doesn't respect If-None-Match

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-2016

I'm programmatically downloading a file from a Sharepoint 2016 document library. The URL goes:

https://hostname.com/Site/Folder/_layouts/15/download.aspx?{long, long URL}

The site emits the ETag header, but when I send a request with an If-None-Match, providing the ETag *I just got*, there's no `304 Not Modified` response, it's 200 and the whole document again.

The ETag header I'm receiving goes:

```
ETag: "{EED54197-A30B-4625-9EBA-8DC7F9D62CF3},1435"
```

The request header then goes:

```
If-None-Match: "{EED54197-A30B-4625-9EBA-8DC7F9D62CF3},1435"
```

I'm testing the same setup against a static file in IIS - it works as expected, 304 comes.

What am I missing, please? Could it be an oversight in the Sharepoint API?

EDIT: one unsatisfactory workaround involves firing a HEAD request first and manually matching the ETag values on the client.

Comment: How are you downloading it ? Are you using REST api or C# CSOM ?

Comment: In the program, C# WebClient.OpenRead(), but I'm testing with a standalone Web client "I'm Only Resting", and it shows the same discrepancy in behavior between Sharepoint and a static file in IIS.

Comment: Apologies, but can you tell me about the end goal ? What is it that you are trying to achieve ? Also, there is an informative article [here](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/improving-performance-of-sharepoint-sites/part-13-etag-header/), probably it might help you.

Comment: There's an Excel sheet in Sharepoint that I parse in my program. It changes once in 2-3 days, but the customer wants better latency than that, so I pull it every hour. I'd like to short out processing if it hasn't changed since the last run. I don't control the source Sharepoint.

Comment: Well, you can try the OOTB sharepoint endpoint `https://hostname.com/Site/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Site/Folder/test.xlsx')?$select=TimeLastModified` which gives you the last modified time of the document. Based on that, you can choose to download or not download your file. For that, you need the actual file name as well as the relative location of that file. For test purpose, try to hit this endpoint in the browser/postman with your actual file name and path. I think this would be the correct approach instead of the etag.

Comment: Still two requests, but oh well :)